# how to subclass UITableViewCell if the content/height of each cell varies

Tags: iphone, uitableview, subclassing

I have a UITableView. The height and content of each cell of the table view varies, depending on the data feeding to the cell. To give an example - some might have pictures, some might only have text; some might have 1 picture, some might have more than 1 picture. So, I am thinking about subclassing the UITableViewCell so I can use the subclass in other table views that I might have.

Is there some sample code that I can follow to achieve that goal - subclassing UITableViewCell, varied content, varied height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This has been asked many times.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uitableviewcell+variable+height)

Also, you don't need to subclass to get variable row height, nor to put custom controls into the cell, but for the latter case subclassing may be convenient.